# What is the difference between my spans?

Tags: php, css

I have two spans inside my echo:

```
echo '<div class="elementsDiv" id="'.$row['objekt_nr']."_".$row['element_nr'].'" data-weight="'.$row['vikt'].'"  data-nr="'.$row['element_nr'].'" style="width: '.$langd.'px; height: '.$bredd.'px;><span class="elementDivNr">'.$row['element_nr'].'</span><span class="elementDivWeight">'.round($viktT, 2).' t</span></div>';
```

Span with class: "elementDivNr" & span with class: "elementDivWeight".

I try to set a background color for the spans with CSS:

```
span.elementDivNr{
  background-color: red !important;
}
span.elementDivWeight{
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Now... why is only one of them getting the red color background? How can I search for "overrides"?

[image]

My code is pretty big in both CSS and JS as this is a "DnD" application.

**UPDATE**
It is strange is that I cannot access this span at all with CSS.

```
span.elementDivNr{
  background-color: red !important;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Changing font size has no effect either.

**UPPDATE**

https://jsfiddle.net/1u8evdr8/

Comment: Can you please add a snippet of the problem?

Comment: You may have another `!important` rule later on in your css that's overwriting it. That's why `!important` should be used only when absolutely necessary...

Comment: `.elementDivNr , .elementDivWeight{
  background-color: red !important;
}`

Comment: @StefanoZanini Can this happen even if the classname isn´t the same? I have important on some places but no one on the same class.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, can you create a snippet that displays it?

Comment: Fiddle added...

Comment: That can happen if the `!important` rule addresses your element in a different way (like referring to `span` in general, or by addressing all the children of some parent element).

Comment: There are so many errors in your html, so it is not creating the first span tag. Check the code in the php echo or in loop

Comment: @sai The error reproduces because it´s a php loop. All it was just missing a closure ".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a closing " on your style tag of your DIV.

So this:

```
echo '<div class="elementsDiv" id="'.$row['objekt_nr']."_".$row['element_nr'].'" data-weight="'.$row['vikt'].'"  data-nr="'.$row['element_nr'].'" style="width: '.$langd.'px; height: '.$bredd.'px;><span class="elementDivNr">'.$row['element_nr'].'</span><span class="elementDivWeight">'.round($viktT, 2).' t</span></div>';
```

Should be this:

```
echo '<div class="elementsDiv" id="'.$row['objekt_nr']."_".$row['element_nr'].'" data-weight="'.$row['vikt'].'"  data-nr="'.$row['element_nr'].'" style="width: '.$langd.'px; height: '.$bredd.'px;"><span class="elementDivNr">'.$row['element_nr'].'</span><span class="elementDivWeight">'.round($viktT, 2).' t</span></div>';
```

Comment: Thank you. i just found it to ;D

Answer (score 1):

Found it..

I was missing a closure " in the style prop.

Answer (score 1):

If you observe style attr is not closed with " in the code please close it

```
 echo '<div class="elementsDiv" id="'.$row['objekt_nr']."_".$row['element_nr'].'" 
data-weight="'.$row['vikt'].'"  
data-nr="'.$row['element_nr'].'" 
style="width: '.$langd.'px; height: '.$bredd.'px;"><span class="elementDivNr">'.$row['element_nr'].'</span><span class="elementDivWeight">'.round($viktT, 2).' t</span></div>';
```